# How can I use FakeItEasy with HttpClient, in a unit test?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, fakeiteasy

I'm trying to figure out how to use FakeItEasy with the HttpClient, given the following code:

```
public Foo(string key, HttpClient httpClient = null)
{ .. }

public void DoGet()
{
    ....

    if (_httpClient == null)
    {
        _httpClient = new HttpClient();
    }

    var response = _httpClient.GetAsync("user/1);
}

public void DoPost(foo Foo)
{
    if (_httpClient == null)
    {
        _httpClient = new HttpClient();
    }

    var formData = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"Name", "Joe smith"},
        {"Age", "40"}
    };    

    var response = _httpClient.PostAsync("user", 
        new FormUrlEncodedContent(formData));
}
```

So i'm not sure how to use `FakeItEasy`, to fake out the HttpClient's `GetAsync` and `PostAsync` methods.

production code will not pass in the HttpClient, but the unit test will pass in the fake instance, made by FakeItEasy.

eg.

```
[Fact]
public void GivenBlah_DoGet_DoesSomething()
{
    // Arrange.
    var httpClient A.Fake<HttpClient>(); // <-- need help here.
    var foo = new Foo("aa", httpClient);

    // Act.
    foo.DoGet();

    // Assert....
}
```

#### UPDATE:

I grok that FiE (and most mocking packages) works on interfaces or virtual methods. So for this question, lets just *prentend* that the `GetAsync` and `PostAsync` methods are virtual ... please :)

Comment: I stand by my usual answer to this: don't unit test your bottom level I/O layer - the ROI is too low

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's my (more or less) general purpose FakeHttpMessageHandler.

```
public class FakeHttpMessageHandler : HttpMessageHandler
{
    private HttpResponseMessage _response;

    public static HttpMessageHandler GetHttpMessageHandler( string content, HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode )
    {
        var memStream = new MemoryStream();

        var sw = new StreamWriter( memStream );
        sw.Write( content );
        sw.Flush();
        memStream.Position = 0;

        var httpContent = new StreamContent( memStream );

        var response = new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            StatusCode = httpStatusCode,
            Content = httpContent
        };

        var messageHandler = new FakeHttpMessageHandler( response );

        return messageHandler;
    }

    public FakeHttpMessageHandler( HttpResponseMessage response )
    {
        _response = response;
    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync( HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken )
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpResponseMessage>();

        tcs.SetResult( _response );

        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

Here is an example of it being used from one of my tests that expects some JSON as a return value.

```
const string json = "{\"success\": true}";

var messageHandler = FakeHttpMessageHandler.GetHttpMessageHandler( 
    json, HttpStatusCode.BadRequest );
var httpClient = new HttpClient( messageHandler );
```

You would now inject `httpClient` into your class under test (using whatever injection mechanism you prefer) and when `GetAsync` is called your `messageHandler` will spit back the result you told it to.

Comment: That's really really really helpful, Craig! This brings me to another question - why are you creating a custom message handler, instead of just an HttpClient wrapper?

Comment: I find this to be cleaner than using a wrapper. In my production code I can continue to use HttpClient instead of having to remember to use the wrapper. From experience I find wrappers to just be a PITA. Maybe for something like HttpClient, where you only have a couple of methods, it's not so bad. I think it's largely a matter of preference and what your established standards are which approach you take.

Comment: Thank you Craig. You helped me tremendously.

Answer (score 7):

You could also create an `AbstractHandler` on which you can intercept a public abstract method. For instance:

```
public abstract class AbstractHandler : HttpClientHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(SendAsync(request.Method, request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri));
    }

    public abstract HttpResponseMessage SendAsync(HttpMethod method, string url);
}
```

Then you can intercept calls to the `AbstractHandler.SendAsync(HttpMethod method, string url)` like:

```
// Arrange
var httpMessageHandler = A.Fake<AbstractHandler>(options => options.CallsBaseMethods());
A.CallTo(() => httpMessageHandler.SendAsync(A<HttpMethod>._, A<string>._)).Returns(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) { Content = new StringContent("Result")});
var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpMessageHandler);

// Act
var result = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://google.com/");

// Assert
Assert.Equal("Result", await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
A.CallTo(() => httpMessageHandler.SendAsync(A<HttpMethod>._, "https://google.com/")).MustHaveHappenedOnceExactly();
```

More information can be found on this blog: https://www.meziantou.net/mocking-an-httpclient-using-an-httpclienthandler.htm

Comment: I believe this will fail if I have return type other than "HttpResponseMessage" .. ?

Comment: This is much cleaner than Craig's answer (even though his approach is as good). Thanks, this helped me a lot!

Answer (score 3):

I did something like this when I needed to interact with the Gravatar service. I tried to use fakes/mocks but found it was impossible with HttpClient. Instead, I came up with a custom HttpMessageHandler class that lets me pre-load the expected response, along these lines:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Tigra.Gravatar.LogFetcher.Specifications
    {
    /// <summary>
    ///   Class LoggingHttpMessageHandler.
    ///   Provides a fake HttpMessageHandler that can be injected into HttpClient.
    ///   The class requires a ready-made response message to be passed in the constructor,
    ///   which is simply returned when requested. Additionally, the web request is logged in the
    ///   RequestMessage property for later examination.
    /// </summary>
    public class LoggingHttpMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
        {
        internal HttpResponseMessage ResponseMessage { get; private set; }
        internal HttpRequestMessage RequestMessage { get; private set; }

        public LoggingHttpMessageHandler(HttpResponseMessage responseMessage)
            {
            ResponseMessage = responseMessage;
            }

        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
            RequestMessage = request;
            return Task.FromResult(ResponseMessage);
            }
        }
    }
```

Then my test context setup goes something like this:

```
public class with_fake_gravatar_web_service
    {
    Establish context = () =>
        {
        MessageHandler = new LoggingHttpMessageHandler(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK));
        GravatarClient = new HttpClient(MessageHandler);
        Filesystem = A.Fake<FakeFileSystemWrapper>();
        Fetcher = new GravatarFetcher(Committers, GravatarClient, Filesystem);
        };

    protected static LoggingHttpMessageHandler MessageHandler;
    protected static HttpClient GravatarClient;
    protected static FakeFileSystemWrapper Filesystem;
    }
```

Then, here's an example of a test (specification) that uses it:

```
[Subject(typeof(GravatarFetcher), "Web service")]
public class when_fetching_imagaes_from_gravatar_web_service : with_fake_gravatar_web_service
    {
    Because of = () =>
        {
        var result = Fetcher.FetchGravatars(@"c:\"); // This makes the web request
        Task.WaitAll(result.ToArray());
        //"http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/".md5_hex(lc $email)."?d=404&size=".$size; 
        UriPath = MessageHandler.RequestMessage.RequestUri.GetComponents(UriComponents.Path, UriFormat.Unescaped);
        };

    It should_make_request_from_gravatar_dot_com =
        () => MessageHandler.RequestMessage.RequestUri.Host.ShouldEqual("www.gravatar.com");

    It should_make_a_get_request = () => MessageHandler.RequestMessage.Method.ShouldEqual(HttpMethod.Get);
    // see https://en.gravatar.com/site/check/tim@tigranetworks.co.uk
    It should_request_the_gravatar_hash_for_tim_long =
        () => UriPath.ShouldStartWith("avatar/df0478426c0e47cc5e557d5391e5255d");

    static string UriPath;
    }
```

You can see the full source at http://stash.teamserver.tigranetworks.co.uk/users/timlong/repos/tigra.gravatar.logfetcher/browse

Comment: on a side note: what testing framework is that? It reminds me of NSpec, which I'm using.

Answer (score 2):

FakeItEasy, like most mocking libraries, does not create proxies for non-abstract components. In the case of `HttpClient`, the `GetAsync` and `PostAsync` methods are neither `virtual` nor `abstract`, so you can't create stub implementations of them directly. See https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/wiki/What-can-be-faked.

In this case, you need a different abstraction as a dependency - one which `HttpClient` can fulfill, but so could other implementations, including mocks/stubs.

Comment: Essentially, yeah. I'd define an interface and have a concrete implementation of it that acts as a proxy to `HttpClient` used at run-time, with a mock used for tests.

Comment: You can create a wrapper but that can get to be a bit of a PITA to maintain. Creating a HttpMessageHandler that can be faked and injected is a better solution. I've got a general purpose class that will do that at work, I'll post it tomorrow.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't answering your question directly, but I wrote a library a while back that provides an API for stubbing out requests/responses. It's pretty flexible, and supports ordered/unordered matching as well as a customisable fallback system for unmatched requests.

It's available on GitHub here: https://github.com/richardszalay/mockhttp